# Journal turnaround time of 18 months

Tags: paper-submission, economics

I submitted a paper to an economics journal. They have promptly replied to let me know that the review process generally takes 12 to 18 months. I also have to give them a go-ahead confirming their policies before they can begin the review (so I could effectively withdraw at this point). Since this is my first paper, I do not want to be too picky about journal timelines. However, I also planned to apply for a PhD at the end of the year (less than 12 months), and was hoping for a better chance to be able to put a publication on my CV.

My question being: should I attempt to get published faster with a different journal, or is this timeline of 12-18 months acceptable to stick around with?

Comment: Submission times vary between journals and between disciplines, and I can't comment on economics journals. For your PhD application, you could always list the manuscript as _under review_, hence, all is not lost if the manuscript isn't published.

Comment: I work in a field (not economics) where a review process takes 1.5-2 years. (And it takes another year after the article has been accepted for it to actually appear).  Everyone in the field knows that. A paper is not discounted just because it is under review. Any concern about the quality of the work can be addressed by a quick reading of the paper.

Comment: Do you have another journal in mind that has a similar reputation but is substantially faster? I Would not sacrifice impact for speed.

Comment: This is a very good question to ask, because it is so very field specific. In computer science-related areas, this would be a crazy long amount of time - yet in economics I'm told that a year or more is not at all uncommon (and that most papers are rejected multiple times if you target top journals, so stories detailing 5+ years in review are not uncommon either) - but I'm not familiar enough first-hand with econ to give a confidence answer of the current norms in the field over all.

Comment: I assume that is turnaround time conditional on the paper going out to reviewers, correct?

Comment: For a sense of Econ journal turnaround times, see here. https://www.econjobrumors.com/journals.php

Answer (score -4):

I advise to move to a faster journal AND to make sure the papers are absolutely as clean as you can make them in logic, writing, etc. so that they fly through reviews.